# Paginate Advanced Custom Fields results in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, pagination

I'm currently using the 'Advanced Custom Field' WordPress plugin, and I'm wondering if it's possible to paginate my results.

Here is the code I'm using on a custom page template:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'meta_key' => 'course_date', 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'category' => 2 );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<!--- CONTENT --->  

<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: do you want the post loop to be paginate?

Comment: Yes, paginate the "results" if there are more than 5 posts for example.

Comment: why you added advance custom filed in your question? there seems no any connection with ACf

Comment: The results are currently ordered by "course_date" which is a ACF entry. The displayed posts are pulled from Category 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use WP_Query class  http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'meta_key' => 'course_date', 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'cat' => 2 ,'paged'=>$paged);
$catpost_ = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($catpost_->have_posts() ) : 
    while ($catpost_->have_posts() ) : $catpost_->the_post();

 ?>

<!--- CONTENT --->
<?php
 endwhile; 
 endif;
 wp_reset_query();?>
<?php
            $big=76;
        $args = array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
'total'        => $catpost_->max_num_pages,
'current'      => $paged,
'prev_next'    => True,
    'prev_text'    => __('Previous'),
    'next_text'    => __('Next'),

'type'         => 'list');
// ECHO THE PAGENATION 
echo paginate_links( $args );
endwhile;
?>
```

this might work for you.

Comment: Great, that paginates everything nicely. However, it seems to pull in ALL posts, instead of posts from a certain category. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: if this solve your problem mark your answer as correct. this will help me get reputation :p

Comment: Done, thanks again for your help. Quick question regarding the category, would it be possible to display posts from a certain category - rather than all of them?

Comment: My mistake. I can use 'cat' rather than 'category'.